# Mysql Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me please? Inner join query working fine. but query displaying duplicate data. I don't to display duplicate data. 
here is my query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.class, t1.classid, t2.classid, t2.option_name
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.classid = t2.classid
```

Here is output

```
"COLOR";"456";"456";"Nude"
"COLOR";"456";"456";"Ivory"
"COLOR";"456";"456";"Black"
"COLOR";"456";"456";"Coral"
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Black"
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Coral"
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Nude"
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Ivory"
"SIZE";"460";"460";"Large"
"SIZE";"460";"460";"Medium"
"SIZE";"460";"460";"Small"
"SIZE";"470";"470";"Large"
"SIZE";"470";"470";"Small"
"SIZE";"470";"470";"Medium"
"COLOR";"476";"476";"White"
"COLOR";"476";"476";"Black"
"SIZE";"477";"477";"Small"
```

But i don't to display duplicate data. for example which is displaying here.

```
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Black"
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Black"
"COLOR";"459";"459";"Black"
"COLOR";"460";"60";"Black"
```

is there any way?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just want to group it by names? You seem to be calling a duplicated data what seems to have different ids...

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.class, t1.classid, t2.classid, t2.option_name
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.classid = t2.classid
GROUP BY t1.class,t2.option_name
```